# Does it make sense to steep wheat in cold water as it is heating up?

Tags: recipe, steeping, wheat

I'm actually not talking about [cold steeping](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1830/what-is-cold-steeping). The [recipe](http://beerrecipes.org/showrecipe.php?recipeid=185) I'm using says

> Put 2.5 gallons of cold, filtered water into pot. Added malted wheat (in muslin bag) to pot and brought the water to 180 degrees. Steeped the wheat for 30 minutes. Removed bag of wheat and brought the water to boil.

It *sounds* like it's saying the wheat should be added to the pot while the water's still cold, but that doesn't make sense to me. It must mean to bring the water to 180 degrees *first*, *then* steep for 30 minutes, right?

Comment: I'm not totally sure whether wheat has all the same enzymes as barley, but barley would be pass through [several important temperature ranges](http://www.howtobrew.com/section3/chapter14-1.html) as you heat it from cold to 180. Considering that the wheat is only 1/7th of your recipe, the impact might not be huge. But it does 'make sense'.

Comment: Thanks @Pepi, that does make more sense now—I'll try that next time I run into this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way will work and not make much difference.  However, if you steep at 180 you'll denature the enzymes that convert the starches to sugar.  The steep should be done between 145-160F for best results.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps the author meant for us to begin steeping as the water heats (passing through the 145-160F range), as a way of saving time. Our OG was lower than expected so maybe it was because, as you say, we denatured the enzymes required to produce as much sugar. (Or would that effect be negligible?)

Comment: Yeah, with so little wheat it wouldn't make a big difference.